# Facebook Comments Cutting Off

Tags: javascript, facebook, comments

I've entered this into my code to use facebook comments:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div><script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1"></script><fb:comments href="google.com" num_posts="10" width="610"></fb:comments>
```

But it cuts of the comments like this http://cl.ly/77fB and the loading graphic doesn't go away. I've tried removing all css that I have and js and it still does the same thing. I looked that code and the iframe that the facebook comments api generates sets a height of 200px. Here's the iframe source code:

```
<iframe id="f1c27030c" name="f1f67bf5c4" scrolling="no" style="border-top-style: none; border-right-style: none; border-bottom-style: none; border-left-style: none; border-width: initial; border-color: initial; overflow-x: hidden; overflow-y: hidden; height: 200px; width: 610px; " class="fb_ltr" src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/comments.php?channel_url=http%3A%2F%2Fstatic.ak.fbcdn.net%2Fconnect%2Fxd_proxy.php%3Fversion%3D2%23cb%3Df3ec50dad4%26origin%3Dfile%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%252Ff17ab9b71%26relation%3Dparent.parent%26transport%3Dpostmessage&amp;href=google.com&amp;locale=en_US&amp;numposts=12&amp;sdk=joey&amp;width=610"></iframe>
```

Not sure what else to do. Thanks!

**Update:**

So because files I'm loading the comments from are local Chrome is saying it's not safe to load it all: http://cl.ly/77X7

I uploaded the file to my server and it loaded all the way.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: What do you want to happen? [I don't get the loading image](http://jsfiddle.net/wesley_murch/dZkdP/) and it looks like you have it set to 10 posts. Do you want a scroll bar or to show all 10 posts?

Comment: I want it to not cut it off. It shouldn't need a scroll bar. If you go to http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/comments/ and set it to 10 comments it doesn't cut it off, it shows all ten comments.

Comment: Sorry, I think I understand the question now. You're getting the wrong height returned from the API, is that it? Still though - it seems to work for me: http://jsfiddle.net/wesley_murch/dZkdP/2/

Comment: looks good in jfiddle or some reason but I I view it in my site it still does this: http://cl.ly/76xR

Comment: Even when I make an html file with nothing it but the facebook code it still produces this in my browser: http://cl.ly/76Q1 - I've tried disabling all my chrome extensions to see if it causes the problem but it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

This comes from the fact that you put google.com as the URL : Facebook servers tries to contact google.com to finish loading your comments.

Try with localhost instead of google.com, it will show [the error message](http://cl.ly/2U1h1m090a2t1Z3j3t42).

So you have to put the URL of the page on which the comments are displayed. It will not work otherwise.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Not the issue of it being able to connect to a host or not. It's the api is generating a height of 200px-ish which is cutting off the comments no matter what url I use or how many comments i have it return: http://cl.ly/76xR

Comment: Even when I make an html file with nothing it but the facebook code it still produces this in my browser: http://cl.ly/76Q1 - I've tried disabling all my chrome extensions to see if it causes the problem but it doesn't.